# An interesting equation

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

Earlier today my friend, a mathematician, gave me a white bag with this equation on it:

> SIΛ°H

What on Earth is in the bag?

Comment: Am I missing something? :) Wheres the "equation" part of this equation?

Comment: @PiotrPytlik, My friend has asked me to work out the other side of the equation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> The bag is full of bread.

Argument:

> HoVIS Ltd is a British company that produces flour and bread:
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hovis
>
>  The inscription "SIΛ°H" is "HoVIS" upside down.

Comment: But if you put the bag upside down, the things will fall out.

Answer (score 11):

The bag is full of:

> Flour.
>  You were holding it upside down, it actually says "HOVIS"

Comment: I feel pretty dumb.

Comment: (apparently it's a british thing)

Comment: @question_asker spoiler ? :}

Comment: @Pogrindis haha FINE

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is the other product they make, as stated by Gamow! +1 for technically being correct

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre well that doesn't make any sense. Hovis packaging for bread is transparent, so you can see the bread. Warburtons have an opaque white wax-paper packaging. The question clearly states that the bag is white!

Comment: I was in Sainsbury's earlier and saw some, must have been crust less or something along those lines but it was bread for sure! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ahhh semantics; so crucial, yet so unloved!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bag of:

> Hovis bread - the "equation" is the name (EDIT: just saw it in the supermarket and see the 'o' is lower case) "HoVIS" upside down and (EDIT: *perhaps*) scrunched up a little.